# Stop python from closing on error

Tags: python, debugging

In python when running scripts is there a way to stop the console window from closing after spitting out the traceback?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you doing this on a Windows OS, you can prefix the target of your shortcut with:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /K <command>
```

This will prevent the window from closing when the command exits.

Comment: For those using a batch file: My batch file previously contained the line `python -m Projects` to start Python and automatically import my Projects module.  Changed this to `cmd /K python -m Projects` and it worked as advertised, with the cmd console staying open after an error.

Comment: this is not working only prevents from closing windows command prompt . but not python prompt

Comment: This solution forces you to manually close the window (or kill the cmd.exe process) after viewing the traceback, which may return different exit codes than you prefer. If your would like to tell the program when to close the window, say by pressing Enter, see @Torsten Marek s answer below.

Answer (score 34):

You can register a top-level exception handler that keeps the application alive when an unhandled exception occurs:

```
def show_exception_and_exit(exc_type, exc_value, tb):
    import traceback
    traceback.print_exception(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
    raw_input("Press key to exit.")
    sys.exit(-1)

 import sys
 sys.excepthook = show_exception_and_exit
```

This is especially useful if you have exceptions occuring inside event handlers that are called from C code, which often do not propagate the errors.

Comment: +1, this even works if the exception is during imports, without having to re-indent the entire file to put a try around it. It also works when *not* running from a batch file, for example with ShellExecuteEx.

Comment: but what are those `exc_type, exc_value, tb` arguments? (I'm using python 3.6)

Comment: This is a great solution for returning custom error codes to ```WScript.Shell``` objects in VBA while still showing the exceptions.

Comment: Also, the three arguments in ```traceback.print_exception()``` are the exception type, its return value, and the traceback.

Comment: Finally, the traceback argument CANNOT be named ```traceback```

Comment: A more concise version (that also uses Python3's input() instead of raw_input()) is:

`import sys, traceback`
`sys.excepthook = lambda *args: (traceback.print_exception(*args), input())`

Answer (score 15):

```
try:
    #do some stuff
    1/0 #stuff that generated the exception
except Exception as ex:
    print ex
    raw_input()
```

Comment: You might want to use `traceback.print_exc()` instead of `print ex` for the more verbose stacktrace

Answer (score 8):

You could have a second script, which imports/runs your main code. This script would catch all exceptions, and print a traceback (then wait for user input before ending)

Assuming your code is structured using the `if __name__ == "__main__": main()` idiom..

```
def myfunction():
    pass

class Myclass():
    pass

def main():
    c = Myclass()
    myfunction(c)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

..and the file is named "myscriptname.py" (obviously that can be changed), the following will work

```
from myscriptname import main as myscript_main

try:
    myscript_main()
except Exception, errormsg:
    print "Script errored!"
    print "Error message: %s" % errormsg
    print "Traceback:"
    import traceback
    traceback.print_exc()
    print "Press return to exit.."
    raw_input()
```

(Note that `raw_input()` has been replaced by `input()` in [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html))

If you don't have a `main()` function, you would use put the import statement in the `try:` block:

```
try:
    import myscriptname
except [...]
```

A better solution, one that requires no extra wrapper-scripts, is to run the script either from IDLE, or the command line..

On Windows, go to Start > Run, enter `cmd` and enter. Then enter something like..

```
cd "\Path\To Your\ Script\"
\Python\bin\python.exe myscriptname.py
```

(If you installed Python into `C:\Python\`)

On Linux/Mac OS X it's a bit easier, you just run `cd /home/your/script/` then `python myscriptname.py`

The easiest way would be to use IDLE, launch IDLE, open the script and click the run button (`F5` or `Ctrl+F5` I think). When the script exits, the window will not close automatically, so you can see any errors

Also, as [Chris Thornhill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779675/stop-python-from-closing-on-error/779693#779693) suggested, on Windows, you can create a shortcut to your script, and in it's Properties prefix the target with..

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /K [existing command]
```

From http://www.computerhope.com/cmd.htm:

> ```
> /K command - Executes the specified command and continues running.
> ```

Answer (score 8):

On UNIX systems (Windows has already been covered above...) you can change the interpreter argument to include the -i flag:

#!/usr/bin/python -i

From the man page:

> -i
>
> When a script is passed as first argument or the -c option is used, enter interactive mode after executing the script or the command. It does not read the $PYTHONSTARTUP file. This can be useful to inspect global variables or a stack trace when a script raises an exception.

Comment: This even works on Windows (using Python 3)! Great solution, as it allows interaction with the same script afterwards.

Answer (score 4):

In windows instead of double clicking the py file you can drag it into an already open CMD window, and then hit enter. It stays open after an exception.

Dan

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at answer of this question: [How to find exit code or reason when atexit callback is called in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9741351/how-to-find-exit-code-or-reason-when-atexit-callback-is-called-in-python)

You can just copy this `ExitHooks` class, then customize your own `foo` function then register it to `atexit`.

```
import atexit
import sys, os

class ExitHooks(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.exit_code = None
        self.exception = None

    def hook(self):
        self._orig_exit = sys.exit
        sys.exit = self.exit
        sys.excepthook = self.exc_handler

    def exit(self, code=0):
        self.exit_code = code
        self._orig_exit(code)

    def exc_handler(self, exc_type, exc, *args):
        self.exception = exc

hooks = ExitHooks()
hooks.hook()

def goodbye():
    if not (hooks.exit_code is None and hooks.exception is None):
        os.system('pause')
#       input("\nPress Enter key to exit.")

atexit.register(goodbye)
```

Answer (score 2):

if you are using windows you could do this

```
    import os

    #code here 

    os.system('pause')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear, but I assume that the python interpreter exits (and therefore the calling console window closes) when an exception happens.

You need to modify your python application to catch the exception and print it without exiting the interpreter. One way to do that is to print "press ENTER to exit" and then read some input from the console window, effectively waiting for the user to press Enter.