# Getting the exit code within a __del__ function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'd like to do a clean shutdown of a class that does one task when exiting normally, and not under something like exit(1).  How can I determine the current exit code.  Example:

```
import sys
import atexit

def myexit():
    print("atexit")
atexit.register(myexit)

class Test(object):
    def __init(self):
        pass
    def __del__(self):
        print("here")
        # print(sys.exit_code) # How do I get this???

x = Test()
exit(1)
```

which produces:

```
atexit
here
```

But in neither of those places do I know how to get the exit code passed to sys.exit().

There was [other
answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9741351/how-to-find-exit-code-or-reason-when-atexit-callback-is-called-in-python)
but it doesn't seem wise to implement a forced wrapper from another
reusable module.

Comment: Don't use `__del__`. There's no guarantee that it'll be called.

Comment: Also there's no guarantee that Python is shutting down at all when `__del__` is called.

Comment: Instead of trying to detect an exit on failure, why not use a context manager that detects uncaught exceptions (which includes `SystemExit`)?

Comment: Well, my solution may indeed not be the best.  But the goal is that any time a module with an open file handle gets released/destroyed/whatever it writes a final line to the file.  *except* when something like exit(1) is called, which is clearly an error case.  So the reality is that __del__ likely is the right place under most condititions but I functionally *don't* want it to get called during exit(1) scenarios.