# How to get exit code in atexit callback function?

Tags: python-3.x

I would like to print the exit code in a function registered by `atexit`.

```
import atexit, sys, os

@atexit.register
def goodbye():
    print('Exit code', sys.???)
```

My script loads some not-standard modules which may raise an exception or call exit() and in all cases I would like to write the exit code to a log file. I checked the `sys` and `os` modules, but I found no such attribute of method.

**UPDATE**

The issue is more complicated than I thought. For `quit()`, `exit()` and `sys_exit()` `atexit` function is called. Actually they can be called practically with anything! Their argument can be empty, number, text or any class, object and anything else and this value is in the `args` argument of an SystemExit exception.
But not for os._exit(), os.abort(). They behaves more like the C `exit()` and `abort()`, but should not be used as the housekeeping activities would be skipped!

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9741351/how-to-find-exit-code-or-reason-when-atexit-callback-is-called-in-python)  question, it may be helpful.

Comment: @GiorgiImerlishvili Thanks. I have seen this solution, but it is a bit more complex, then it supposed to be. In `Perl` it is like `END { print "Exit code: $?\n";}`. It is a bit strange to me at the `atexit` callback I can not even read the `SystemExit` exception, which was thrown as `sys.exc_info()` returns `(None, None, None)`.